# Accepting A PayPal Payment Through A URL With No Javascript/Form?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a program running in an environment that supports URLs, but no javascript.

Say it's a Word document (though it's not).

Is there a way to craft the PayPal payment URL such that it's all that I need, without the requirement of an HTML form or Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://paypal.me basically exists for simple things

You can create a Buy Now button via https://www.paypal.com/buttons with NO dropdown menus or text fields (which require HTML) and then, once you've generated your button code, clicking on the "Email" link above will give you a URL.

---

If you also want the URL to have editable fields, then before you create the button, in Step 2 uncheck the option to save the button at PayPal, generate the code, and click the link to remove code protection.  Variables are documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#technical-variables

Comment: Thanks, Preston! That definitely got me off and pointed in the right direction. Do you know if it's possible to send "custom" data with the email link? I basically want to send a special field that identifies the customer. Is that possible with the "editable field" approach you mentioned?

Comment: Appropriately enough, the parameter you can use is called `custom`.  You can add  `&custom=blahblah` to any of the button URLs , whether the default hosted kind or made editable (by unchecking the Step 2 Save and removing code protection)

Comment: Thanks again, @Preston!